# Can i create a classic VB array in C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, arrays

I am new to  .net and i have to convert some old vb code to c#.

I don't understand what kind of data is this ?

```
Dim b(0 To 3) As Byte
b(0) = &H4A
b(1) = &H46
b(2) = &H49
b(3) = &H43
```

http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2010/03/16/searching-within-byte-arrays.aspx

When i try to  do something like  `Byte a = &H49;` its not allowing.

what is &H4A ?  Can i create  a bye array of these kind of values in C#.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`&H` is used in vb to indicate a hexadecimal literal. In c# you would use `0x`. So `&H4A` becomes `0x4A`

And your whole byte array can be written as:

```
byte[] b = new byte[4];
b[0] = 0x4A;
// ....etc
```

Or even:

```
byte[] b = new byte[] { 0x4A, 0x46, 0x49, 0x43 };
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it in vb like this:

```
  byte[] b = new byte[4];
  b[0] = 0x4a;// 74
  b[1] = 0x46;//70
  b[2] = 0x49;//73
  b[3] = 0x43;//67
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use built in declare method by typing the `TypeOfarray[] arrayname = new TypeOfarray[lengthofarray];` and assign values to specific items by typing `arrayname[index] = value;`.

### Note :

Arrays in C# are zero indexed like VB.net, which means the first index is 0 by default.

Comment: The example in the question explicitly sets the lower index of the array to 0 and it is actually possible to specify an array in c# with a starting index other than 0 if you *really, really* want to. The default in vb if you don't specify a lower bound explicitly depends on whether or not `Option Base` is included.